How can i disable sound recording on my flutter mobile app?
How can I effectively prevent screen recording (including sound) in my Android? Currently, using getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); effectively  blocks screen capture and disables screen recording on Android  (results in a black screen) but allows sound recording.
So, firstly, how can I block both screen and sound recording simultaneously on Android?
Secondly, is there a way to detect when a user initiates screen recording on Android, so I can take appropriate action such as crashing the app?
Additionally, on iOS, I have a listener to detect screen recording and implement measures such as crashing the app or blocking sound recording. How can I achieve similar functionality on android?
I need the easiest and most quick way possible
Currently, using getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); effectively  blocks screen capture and disables screen recording on Android  (results in a black screen) but allows sound recording. I was expecting it to block sound as well.
